# I have a virtualenv activated through virtualenvwrapper but poetry is skipping and creating its own virtualenv

Tags: python-poetry

I have created a virtualenv in virtualenvwrapper with `mkvirtualenv venv-quran-srs-375 -p python3.7` and activated it. Then switched into the project directory and ran `poetry init` and specified python3.7.5 as the dependecy as doing `python -V` inside the virtualenv shows me 3.7.5.

Then I executed `poetry add Django` and I get this message that it is creating the venv since the activated version is 3.8.5 (which is the version that conda has).

```
The currently activated Python version 3.8.5 is not supported by the project (3.7.5).
Trying to find and use a compatible version.
Using python3 (3.7.5)
Creating virtualenv quran-srs-ALPX3iit-py3.7 in /Users/siraj/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs
Using version ^3.2.8 for Django
```

I am fairly new to the python world - so, I am not sure whether there is a conflict here between conda and virtualenvwrapper. I even installed pyenv and did pyenv local 3.7.5 before running poetry init, as specified in the docs. But it is not using the env I have created. Can someone help me figure out the problem here...

here is a pretty-print of my path when I am inside the activated virtualenv.

```
/Users/siraj/.virtualenvs/venv-quran-srs-375/bin
/Users/siraj/.pyenv/shims
/Users/siraj/.local/bin
/Users/siraj/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/bin
/opt/anaconda3/bin
/opt/anaconda3/condabin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

and pyenv versions gives this output - I guess here system refers to 3.8.5 installed by conda

```
  system
* 3.7.5 (set by /Users/siraj/Projects/quran-srs/.python-version)
  3.9.5
```